# How do get Tikz arrows.meta working with Ubuntu and TexLive

Tags: tikz-pgf

The Tikz `arrows.meta` package does not work on my Ubuntu 14.04 installation. When I attempt to compile a Latex file with

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
```

I get the error

```
! I can't find file `tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex'.
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex 
                                              \catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
l.68 \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
```

A Google search yielded a few Tex.SE questions, but those users were all using MikTex, and it wasn't clear to me how the answers applied to Texlive/Ubuntu.

I tried the command line program `tlmgr`, which I believe is designed to make  Ubuntu's installation of Texlive more up to date (otherwise, one has to wait for updates to come through the package system.) I still get the same error though.

How can I get `arrows.meta` to work? :)

Comment: You have to make sure you have PGF 3.0 installed...

Comment: I am not sure what `tlmgr` does on Ubuntu but if you have an earlier version of TeX Live, such as 2013, it will certainly not enable you to update to the latest which is 2014. (I thought that `tlmgr` was typically unable to update at all when packaged by distros but perhaps I'm wrong about that.) If you want to use the latest features, I strongly recommend uninstalling Ubuntu's packages completely and [installing the upstream version](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu).

Comment: Open `texdoc tikz` and check if you have the right version.

Comment: I beg you to install an actual working TeXlive 2014 (including tlmgr).
You should definitve look at http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html were the process is described in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem on Fedora 20. The problem can be resolved by installing the latest `texlive` on Linux. Unfortunately, many distributions do not keep up-to-date versions of `texlive`, so I would advise to remove the version of `texlive` installed from your package manager and to get the latest version from the official website instead. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu users.  I have Ubuntu 14.04.  There is a directory
where the latex processor searches for this file. The directory is:

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/UbuntuTexDir/generic/pgf
```

Hanging from this directory should be the PGS path. You can download
the latest PGF package (which comes .zipped) and after unzipping it copy it just in the "pgf" directory above.  In particular the following file should be on the system.

Be sure that the TEXINPUTS environmental variable has access to this file.

```
  /usr/local/texlive/texm-flocal/tex/UbuntuTexDir/generic/pgf/tpgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install/update the `texlive-pgf` package.

After that, you can always see the PGF/TikZ library source. For example, for RPM-based distros type

```
rpm -ql texlive-pgf | grep arrows.meta
/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex
```

For your Ubuntu, `dpkg -L texlive-pgf | grep arrows.meta` could be very helpful.